# How to Create custom OptionMenu in android

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, optionmenu

[how to set custom option menu like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGYhS.png)

[update image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGYhS.png)

i tryed all answer from stack but didn't find proper answer for making this

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-customize-option-menu-of-toolbar-in-android/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community - plz check updated image

Answer (score 1):

Just make a layout then put items into it and set layout invisible after click on button **options menu** set visibility of layout on visible.

Comment: i want to set this into recycle view